# solr CSV update mapping parameter

Tags: solr

thanks for the previous responses. i have the following file. and i am using the /update/csv handler to index this into solr! my questions is do i have to transform this file before i can index the first field as a date to the required format ... or can i use the map parameter to achieve the same ..

```
    2011-12-16 21:16:36,510 Total: 2139 Free: 1569
    2011-12-16 21:17:07,593 Total: 2139 Free: 1572
    2011-12-16 21:17:38,819 Total: 2139 Free: 1572
    2011-12-16 21:18:09,789 Total: 2138 Free: 1567
    2011-12-16 21:18:40,667 Total: 2139 Free: 1580
```

i tried using the map parameter thus ..

fieldnames=logged_dt,val_s

f.logged_dt.map=* *:*T*Z

basically i want each line to be transformed to this

```
    2011-12-16T21:16:36Z,510 Total: 2139 Free: 1569
```

so it conforms to the specified date format..! am i missing something ? can i use the map parameter to do it or do i need to transform my input file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Update handlers are pretty strict about the formats and dates usually suffer the most.

So, you cannot do this directly in CSV. And **map** does not support regular expressions - just direct values.

However, you can use [Update Request Processor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) which can be added to any request processor using update.chain parameter in **solrconfig.xml**. You best bet is to use [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html) (requires Solr 4). It takes [standard Java regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) including group replacement.

Comment: thanks a lot thats exactly what i wanted to do ! and i cud do it pretty easily :)